# Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Hostname' Key being added: 'Hostname' in c#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am trying to push a message to IBM MQ but while adding properties like HostName, channel and Port I am getting below error when I continue the debug without stopping

**Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Hostname'  Key being added: 'Hostname' in c#.**

I have tried to validate as below,

```
if (!MQEnvironment.properties.ContainsKey(strHost) && !MQEnvironment.properties.ContainsKey(intPort) && !MQEnvironment.properties.ContainsKey(strChannel))
                {

                    MQEnvironment.properties.Add("Hostname", strHost);
                    MQEnvironment.properties.Add("Port", intPort);
                    MQEnvironment.properties.Add("Channel", strChannel);
                    MQEnvironment.properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
                }
```

above code contains in my MQ PutMessage method where I am pushing my message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not `strHost` that's already there, it's `"Hostname"`. You'd need to change your checking to be:

```
MQEnvironment.properties.ContainsKey("HostName")
```

etc.

Comment: That is also the case for `intPort` and `strChannel`

Answer (score 2):

Yuk (and a headache for future support).

- First off, the MQEnvironment class is a static class and should ONLY be used for super simple programs.  The IBM MQ best practices is to use a HashTable.
- Second, why are you not using the supplied MQ defines for the key names? (it will eliminate typos)
- Third, you need to review the MQ Knowledge Center for the correct MQ .NET values for 'TRANSPORT_PROPERTY'.  Please see [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029480_.htm?lang=en). There are 4 valid values for MQ .NET:

> MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS - connect as server
>   MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT - connect as non-XA client
>   MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT - connect as XA client
>   MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED - connect as non-XA managed client

Here is the proper way to code it:

```
Hashtable qMgrProp = new Hashtable();
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, strHost);
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, intPort);
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, strChannel);

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, qMgrProp);
```

Comment: From version 7.1 onwards MQ .NET client supports XA transaction in managed mode also.